# Can't view files in sd3

Tags: 14.04, boot

I was recently using windows 8.1 on my Lenovo g400s laptop before I  single booted it to use Ubuntu 14.04. How can I access my Hard disk. I have tried to mount sd3 but it hasn't succeeded. Please help. It shows that there is no free space on the partition sd3 but I can't view the files there.

Comment: How did you try to mount it? what is the output of lsblk?

Comment: I have tried mounting using sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/sda3 /mnt

Comment: NAME             MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1             8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2             8:2    0   244M  0 part /boot
└─sda3             8:3    0   465G  0 part 
  ├─ubuntu--vg-root
                 252:0    0 463.1G  0 lvm  /
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1
                 252:1    0   1.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0               11:0    1   1.1G  0 rom  /media/fkkiprotich/Ubuntu 14.10 amd64
fkkiprotich@Mista-Lenovo-G400s:~$

Comment: Hi Felix, can I assume it is an ntfs partition?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is partition problem.

You should start by checking the partition created by Ubuntu, by going to Ubuntu desktop search and searching disks and click to start disks manager, or from terminal by using:

`gnome-disks`

After starting the utility, look-up manually the partition SD3 you should be able to find out:

Partition type: HPFS/NTFS or Extended or Linux swap or Unallocated space or Linux (file system).

The files which you were using under windows which you are looking for can be only in NTFS or FAT32 types as this type is windows NT file system.

If SD3 is not partitioned as NTFS probably your files were lost during the new partition.

If you find it with NTFS check the mounting status of SD3, and try to mount it.

If SD3 is not allocated, you can allocate it by clicking the + sign to add new partition, and make sure in the contents option of create new partition to choose **don't overwrite existing data**, after the partition is created, mount it and try to find your files.